# Meaning of "nur" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Die Politik hat diesen Wandel zwar erkannt, jedoch fehlte ihr zu einer nachhaltigen Reform der Mut. Daher ist in dieser beklemmenden Situation nur **eins sicher**: Das Ganze soll sich ändern. 88 Prozent der Deutschen wünschen sich, so eine Studie der Bertelsmann-Stiftung, eine »neue Wirtschaftsordnung«. Nur die Politik hat diesen Wandel zwar erkannt, jedoch fehlte ihr zu einer nachhaltigen Reform der Mut. Daher ist in dieser beklemmenden Situation nur eins sicher: Das Ganze soll sich ändern. 88 Prozent der Deutschen wünschen sich, **so** eine Studie der Bertelsmann-Stiftung, eine »neue Wirtschaftsordnung«. **Nur** welche?

1. Bedeutet hier "nur" "aber"?
2. Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "eins sicher" und "etwas Sicheres"?
3. Bedeutet "so" hier "je nachdem"?

Comment: You're mis-parsing the second sentence. "Eins sicher" is not a phrase! "eins" is the subject and "sicher" is the predicate: "Just one thing is certain: ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man kann **nur/einzig** oder **aber/jedoch** verwenden. Inhaltlich bedeutet es dasselbe, die Schlussfolgerung des Sprechers aus der Situation ist jedoch eine andere.

> Daher ist in dieser beklemmenden Situation *nur eins* sicher.

Fast alles ist unsicher. **Nur** eine einzige Sache ist sicher. Das ist zum Fürchten.

> Daher ist in dieser beklemmenden Situation *aber eins* sicher.

Fast alles ist unsicher. **Aber immerhin** eine einzige Sache ist sicher. Das ist doch zumindest schonmal positiv.

---

> Daher ist in dieser beklemmenden Situation *nur eins/nur eines* sicher.
>
> Daher ist in dieser beklemmenden Situation *nur eine Sache* sicher.

Die beiden obigen Sätze bedeuten dasselbe. Nur eine Sache ist sicher, und diese wird (hoffentlich) im folgenden Satz genannt. Der Autor baut mit dieser Konstruktion einen Spannungsbogen auf. Der Satz

> Daher ist in dieser beklemmenden Situation *nur etwas Sicheres* sicher.

enthält hingegen – noch dazu in Form eines Zirkelschlusses – die sichere Sache bereits im selben Satz. Ohne jede Spannung. Alles wird sofort verraten. Jetzt mal ohne den Zirkelschluss:

> Daher ist in dieser beklemmenden Situation *nur* sicher, *dass sich das Ganze ändern soll.*

---

> 88 Prozent der Deutschen wünschen sich, *so* eine Studie der Bertelsmann-Stiftung, eine »neue Wirtschaftsordnung«.

Dieses *so* bedeutet dasselbe wie die Präpositionen *laut* oder *zufolge*:

> *Laut einer Studie der Bertelsmann-Stiftung* wünschen sich 88 Prozent der Deutschen eine »neue Wirtschaftsordnung.
>
> *Einer Studie der Bertelsmann-Stiftung zufolge* wünschen sich 88 Prozent der Deutschen eine »neue Wirtschaftsordnung.

---

> Nur welche?

Niemand weiß es. Das ist schlecht.

> Aber welche?

Es gibt ein paar Möglichkeiten. Welche davon soll es sein?

Also genau dasselbe wie ganz oben, der Sprecher drückt mit dem *nur* Unsicherheit aus.

Comment: nur auf Englisch only, nur welche Wirtschaftsordnung = only which econmic..   aber in diesem Zusammemhang verstehe ich nicht was "nur"hier bedeutet

Comment: *Nur* can mean *only*, but in the above case, it means *I'm lost.* This is similar to the exclamation *But…* You are in the realm of modal particles here. Remember each modal particle (a pure mood indicator without any translateable meaning) has a twin word with a very distinctive meaning. Well, actually this isn't the whole truth, in reality any word may range anywhere inbetween these two extremes. German scholars have simply tried to make some sense of that by calling those "meaningless words" modal particles.

Comment: Take the English word *hell* for example. It has a very distinctive meaning. But people use it more often as a mood indicator. It doesn't mean *hell* then, not even necessarily something hellish, but it just conveys being agitated.

Comment: danke schön meine Lieblingslehrerin

Comment: @user26646 There's also a comparable English phrase: »there's only one thing (that's) certain«.